# Custom Control Class Unknown In My Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I made a custom control in asp.net web form.
I have a master page, my custom control is in the master page. In the `aspx.cs` file I tried to get the control from the master page.

This is the code:

```
if (Master.FindControl("Navbar1") != null)
        ((Controls_Navbar)Master.FindControl("Navbar1")).NavTitle = "Example";
```

The class:

```
public partial class Controls_Navbar : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

It gave me an error: `Compilation Error`, Why?

Comment: The text of the error?

Comment: It give the error on the `Controls_Navbar` when i tried to cast it

Comment: Sure, and what does the error say?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Controls_Navbar' could not be found

Comment: So you declared the control somewhere where your app does not see it. Is it in a separate assembly which is not referenced? Is it in the different namespace which you are not "using"?

Comment: The clasa is not have a namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the namespace of the control class, master class and page class and make sure they match.